# how to build a new json string from existing json string

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have multiple files that contain json data that looks like this:

1.json:

```
[{
    "id": 2100059,
    "email": "",
    "company": "acme",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe"
 }, 
 {
    "id": 2199991,
    "email": "",
    "company": "Widgets Inc",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
 }]
```

2.json:

```
[{
    "id": 123456,
    "email": "",
    "company": "acme",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "GI Jame",
    "last_name": "Adf"
 }, 
 {
    "id": 000001,
    "email": "",
    "company": "Widgets Inc",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "bob",
    "last_name": "billy"
 }]
```

How can I combine these two lists so that it's just one string, with one set of []?

So far, I'm writing the logic read in the contents of each file into separate strings.  But then I'm thinking I should:
1.  json_decode() each string to treat it like an object

Not sure how to append to the object though.
any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I decided to read each file contents into an array, and then try the tips suggested below to use array_merge.  when i do a print_r on my array, it looks like this:  (bogus data, but you should get the idea)

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{"id":2100059,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2129527,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2134804,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2148239,"email":"","company":""}]
    [1] => [{"id":2100059,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2129527,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2134804,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2148239,"email":"","company":""}]

    [2] => [{"id":2100059,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2129527,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2134804,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2148239,"email":"","company":""}
    [3] =>[{"id":2100059,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2129527,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2134804,"email":"","company":""},{"id":2148239,"email":"","company":""}]
)
```

And then this is the logic I have that tries to combine all this into one json string:

```
    print_r($allpages);
    $finaljsonstring ='';
    foreach ($allpages as $item)
    {
        $finaljsonstring = $finaljsonstring + json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($item)));
    }
    echo $finaljsonstring;
```

But something is going wrong.  (I'm calling this as ajax so it's hard to debug) but when i console.log the results from the ajax call, nothing is returned.
Ultimately, what I need to return to the front end is a single array of json strings like this:

[{}, {},{}]

Comment: I believe something like `json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($json1, true),json_decode($json2, true)))` may do the trick here.

Comment: @JNevill pleasesee my EDIT 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_decode()` and `array_merge()` to achieve what you're looking for.

```
<?php
$json_1 = <<<EOD
[{
    "id": 2100059,
    "email": "",
    "company": "acme",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "Jane",
    "last_name": "Doe"
 }, 
 {
    "id": 2199991,
    "email": "",
    "company": "Widgets Inc",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
 }]
EOD;

$json_2 = <<<EOD
[{
    "id": 123456,
    "email": "",
    "company": "acme",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "GI Jame",
    "last_name": "Adf"
 }, 
 {
    "id": 1122,
    "email": "",
    "company": "Widgets Inc",
    "job_title": "",
    "first_name": "bob",
    "last_name": "billy"
 }]
EOD;
```

Example:

```
$json_decoded_1 = json_decode($json_1);

$json_decoded_2 = json_decode($json_2);

$arr_combined = array_merge( $json_decoded_1, $json_decoded_2 );

$json_combined = json_encode($arr_combined);

echo $json_combined;
```

Note you don't have to pass the second `true` parameter on `json_decode()` to convert the string to an array. These items can remain objects when using `array_merge()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hi Samuel, can you take a look at EDIT 1?